# excepter ';', ',' ')' before '&' token error

Tags: c

I have this problem in C: 
I try to create my own scanf because of trailing , here is the code:

```
int cScanf(int& out)
{
        char buffer[5];
        fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);
        return sscanf(buffer, "%d",&out);
}
```

and this is how I call this function in main :

```
if (cScanf(typ) == 1 && (typ > -1 && typ < 37))
```

but when I try to compile my program I get this error:

```
error: excepter ';', ',' ')'` before '&' token
```

Any advise on how to solve this?

Comment: C does not have references (`int& out`). Pass a pointer instead (`int* out`).

Comment: `I try to create my own scanf because of trailing`, what!?

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be

```
int cScanf(int* out)
{
        char buffer[5];
        fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);
        return sscanf(buffer, "%d",*out);
}
```

And you need to pass address of `typ` like

```
if (cScanf(&typ) == 1 && (typ > -1 && typ < 37))
```

But i'm not sure your logic works or not. Just i corrected compilation error

Comment: You are passing int (`*out`) to the scant, which expects int*

Comment: @nio Thanks, modified

Answer (score 2):

With a lack of references in C you have to use a pointer:

```
int cScanf(int* out)
{
    char buffer[5];
    fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);
    return sscanf(buffer, "%d", out);
    // no & before out in sscanf argument, because it already is a pointer
    // and it holds an address to int which sscanf expects.
}
```

Call the code like this:

```
if (cScanf(&typ) == 1 && (typ > -1 && typ < 37))
```

With `&typ` you'll get an address of typ variable, which you can use with a pointer argument.

Answer (score 1):

`int cScanf(int &out)`

This is C++ syntax, in C you do not have references. You need to use pointers instead...

`int cScanf(int *out)`

And therefore your code should be:

```
int cScanf(int *out)
{
        char buffer[5];
        fgets(buffer, 5, stdin);
        return sscanf(buffer, "%d", out);
}
```

You should allocate the memory to `out` (or `typ`) in calling function before passing to `cScanf`. For this purpose you can either use static allocation as:

```
int input, rc;
rc = cScanf(&input);
```

or dynamic allocation:

```
int *p_input, rc;
p_input = malloc(sizeof(int));
if(p_input != NULL)  
    rc = cScanf(p_input);
```